# What does this commentator say?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, pronunciation, questions

I don't know if this is allowed but I want to know what this Commentator says in this video at 7:18 and 7:21 to be exact.

"Slater was (something I do not understand) shoot"

and the other one starts with "well-(something) a cross"

Can anybody tell me what he is saying there?

[Youtube: Birmingham City vs. Hull City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uOo1PqW65A&t=437)

Comment: Sounds like "implored to shoot" and "a well stood-up cross"

Comment: Thank you @KillingTime But implored to shoot is common saying? I didn't understand what he meant by saying that.

Comment: Note that ***[player] was implored to shoot*** is ridiculously clunky phrasing. What the commentator is *trying* to say is something along the lines of *Slater's team-mates and supporters were [somewhat metaphorically] **praying / begging** for him to take the shot [at goal]*. Sports commentators often get their words mixed up like this, but it's not something people wanting to learn English should deliberately copy.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @FumbleFingers

Comment: The title should be "What does this commentator **say**".  Remember, when you use *to do*, you don't conjugate the other verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I dunno how much football you watch but it goes very quickly and sometimes commentators are not paragons of expression in whatever language they happen to be speaking. "implored to shoot" is certainly not clunky if another player gestured to him. So, I think, as an on-the-fly expression, it's fine. In fact, it's pretty terse and to the point.

Comment: @Lambie: Of course it's clunky! Native speakers simply don't normally use the passive with unspecified agent in such contexts. It would almost always be *They begged me to stop*, not *I was begged to stop*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers See what Laconic Droid says....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He says:

> Slator *was implored to shoot**. ["begged" to shoot"]    A **well
> stood-up cross** [shot]. It was Oscar who headed and then Jones
> couldn't keep the ball down.

verb: to shoot, shot, shot [principal parts]
noun: a shot

I am not sure what he means exactly by a well stood-up shot. Probably: He dealt with the shot effectively.  **To stand up to something is [past tense: stood up to it] **: **to deal effectively with a person or situation** [Collins Dictionary]

Some player begged Slator to make the shot. Players do make gestures and so forth to other players. He may even have shouted it out: shoot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Lambie, btw also by saying "Jones couldn't keep the ball down." Is The commentator refers that the player couldn't control the ball or is there a different meaning?

Comment: In football, when you stand-up a cross, the trajectory of the ball is similar to the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle where the intended recipient will head it close to the apex of its flight; typically just after it starts to drop.

Comment: @AlimGölcük - you are correct about "Jones couldn't keep the ball down." The commentator means he was not able to to control his shot and keep the ball low enough to go under the crossbar of the goals.